# How to skip primitive data values while reading from file

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream, datainputstream

I wrote a Java program that reads integers from a file. Five integers were written to that file earlier using the following code:

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
DataOutputStream d=null;
System.out.println("Enter 5 integers");
try{
    d=new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("num.dat"));
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
    d.writeInt(s.nextInt());
    } //for
} //try
catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
finally{
    try{
        d.close()
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}//finally
```

Now while reading the integers from the file **num.dat**, I wish to skip 'n' integers. I used the following code in another class:

```
DataInputStream d=null;
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=0; //stores no. of integers to be skipped
try{
    d=new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("num.dat");
    for (...){
        if(...)
        n++; //condition to skip integers
    } //for
}//try
catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
finally{
    try{
        d.skip(n); //skips n integers
        System.out.println("Requested Integer is "+d.readInt());
        d.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
} //finally
```

The program shows correct output only if I request the first integer of the file. If I try to skip some integers, it either gives no or a wrong output. The integers I entered in the first program weren't one digit but three digit integers. I also tried to skip individual digits of a three digit integer but that also didn't help. Please tell me how I can skip while reading primitive data values.

Comment: Would you give us your imput and wrong and expected outputs?

Comment: Could you also explain why you want to do it like this?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Anderson I'm a newbie. This is what I did from two days' File I/O lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> d.skip(n); //skips n integers
> ```

This interpretation of the [`skip(long n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#skip(long)) method is incorrect: it skips `n` *bytes*, not `n` integers:

> Skips over and discards n bytes of data from the input stream.

To fix this problem, write your own method that calls `d.readInt()` `n` times, and discards the results. You could also do it without a method, simply by adding a loop:

```
try {
    //skips n integers
    for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
        d.readInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Requested Integer is "+d.readInt());
    d.close();
}
catch(Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Yep. skip() skips bytes. But since I didn't get a syntax error, I thought there might as well be a skip() method for primitive values. I'll try what you say and let you know. Thanks :) BTW, if d.readInt() is called n times, and I want to skip to the third of 5 three-digit integers, what should be 'n' ?

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik Every single method of the Java library is fully documented. When you are not sure what a method does, look up its documentation. It may be tricky when the method is inherited, like `skip`, because it's not described on the documentation page for `DataInputStream`. Instead, there's a link at the bottom for all inherited methods. You need to follow that link to see what the method does.

Comment: Thank you for your your solution. It worked perfectly. I just called `d.readInt()` the number of times as the number of integers I wanna skip. And I also learned about `RandomAccess` files and the class' `seek()` method which helps to do this task very easily. Thanks again for your help.